# Clear form field when validation on other field fails

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to clear an input text from validator when validation on other field fails. I've tried using the `setSubmittedValue("")` or `setValue("")`, but it's not working.

The reason I want to do that is because the field is a captcha field and if the validation on other field fails, page will be rendered with a new captcha code and I want the input field to be empty.

the form:

```
<h:form id="form">
   <h:inputText id="otherfieldid" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter"
        validator="#{bean.validateA}"
        validatorMessage="Validation fails" />

    <h:inputText id="fieldid" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter"
        validator="#{bean.validateB}"
        validatorMessage="Validation fails" />
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public Bean {
    public void validateA(FacesContext context,
                UIComponent componentToValidate,
                Object value)
                throws ValidatorException {
        /* validation codes */
    }

    public void validateB(FacesContext context,
                UIComponent componentToValidate,
                Object value)
                throws ValidatorException {

        HtmlInputText ht = 
            (HtmlInputText) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(":form:otherfieldid");

        if (ht != null) {           
            if (ht.getValidatorMessage() != null 
                    || !"".equals(ht.getValidatorMessage())) {              
                ((HtmlInputText) componentToValidate).setSubmittedValue("");
                return;
            }
        }
        /* validation codes */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your `value="#{yourBeam.field}` binding for the input fields? It should be possible to just set this field in the Bean to null, if validation fails...

Comment: I forgot to add that I tried that and binding too, both are not working.